# Python setup runs scripts in his own directory

Tags: python, installation, directory, setup.py, entry-point

I have structure like that

```
src/
   setup.py
   my_folder/
             my_script.py
             my_data.json
```

My `.py` file uses data from `my_data.json` and it simple points to it with path `my_data.json`, because it is rigth next to it? Yeah it works correctly when I run it normally by `python my_script.py` but when I try to make it via setup file and run it with some alias then it's clearly runs from `/src` directory and it doesn't see my `my_data.json` file because it should point to `my_folder/my_data.json`. When I print `os.getcwd()` then I see that `my_script.py` is run from `/src` directory, that's kind of weird...
My setup looks like this:

```
setup(
  name='main',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'my_alias = my_folder.my_script:main'
        ],
    },
    include_package_data=True,
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

Do you have any idea how to force to run my script in his directory not directory where setup is placed?

Comment: try add `'my_alias = my_folder.my_script:main'` to `'my_alias = ../my_folder.my_script:main'`

Comment: Well, it's not correct syntax and I don't think it would work like that because it points to wrong directory in that case

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend avoiding moving into the packages directory if you can avoid it, but something like:

```
import os

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

would probably work.

if you just need to get the resources you included inside of your module, you could do something like this in my_script:

```
import json
import pkg_resources

raw = pkg_resources.resource_string(__name__, 'my_data.json')
data = json.loads(raw)
```

pkg_resources.resource_string returns the contents of my_data.json as a bytestring. There are also .resource_stream and .resource_filename methods if you want to be able to open them as files within python or with a subprocess, respectively. This gives you compatibility with zip_safe environments, which may or may not be useful to you depending on what you're doing.

I'm not sure if its technically required, but I find sometimes setup scripts don't play nicely with automatically adding data files to your package, and some manual intervention like the following is required:

```
setup(
    name='mypackage',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'my_alias = mypackage.my_script:main'
        ],
    },
    package_data={'mypackage': ['*.json']},  # Important addition
    include_package_data=True,
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

Comment: That's quite similar answer. Now I have to go to all my "mains"/scripts and change used paths. While doing few services, which might depend on some kind of files, I don't think that's what I want to do. I would like to run these services without affecting their logic.